# При компиляции приложения в unity выводится такая ошибка

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При компиляции приложения  в unity выводится такая ошибка - скриншот выше

Comment: Мы не можем знать что именно находится по приведённой вами ссылке. Там может быть вирус, например. Засим многие люди просто не пойдут по ссылке, не посмотрят что там и не дадут вам ответа. Лучше всего текст ошибки поместить прямо в тело вопроса текстом или уж выложить скриншот прямо в тело вопроса, чтобы он сразу же тут и отображался. Так вы радикально, в разы, повысите вероятность того, что на ваш вопрос ответят.

Comment: сделал,Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, собственно ошибка в том, что Unity не может найти необходимые SDK android-а по указанному в ошибке пути. Посмотрите установлено ли AndroidSDK и где, если да. Возможно надо будет где-то прописать корректный путь до SDK.

Comment: А вы собственно ошибку переводили? "SDK по указанному пути не обнаружено. [Директория] не существует"

Comment: все решили спасибо. переустановил (директорию удалил- я вспомнил )

Comment: а ввы можете помочь  с этим скриптом                                                                                          using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class helper : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{

    private Rigidbody RB;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RB.useGravity = true;



}

Comment: Чего? Задайте новый вопрос, тут никто не увидит. Кстати, если мой ответ вам помог, давайте я его напишу как ответ, а не как комментарий, чтобы вы могли его принять

Comment: да хорошо.                                                                                                           // я просто достиг лимита не могу уже писать вопрос

Comment: @muramura, примите мой ответ. А что за лимит? Такой бывает?

Comment: да. два вопроса в день.дальше ожидание 24 часа потом снова 2 вопроса и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка переводится как: "Не получилось обнаружить SDK по указанному пути. [Директория] не существует. Android SDK command-line не обнаружен. Убедитесь, что "Command-line Tools" установлена в SDK manager. Если Command-line Tools установлено, но это окно все же показывается, пожалуйста, перезапустите Юнити".

Проще говоря, проверьте существование указанной директории.